How to use SolverConfigOverride class to let the user decide the termination of the solver in Timefold?
I want to override the configuration provided in the XML and application.properties to let the user decide the termination time of the Solver and also to let the user configure the duration of each Phase (including Construction Heuristics and Local Search).
This is the XML config:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<solver xmlns="https://timefold.ai/xsd/solver" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="https://timefold.ai/xsd/solver https://timefold.ai/xsd/solver/solver.xsd">

    <scoreDirectorFactory>
        <constraintProviderClass>
            com.timetablealgo.testingtimetablealgo.solver.TimetableConstraintProvider
        </constraintProviderClass>
    <initializingScoreTrend>ONLY_DOWN/ONLY_DOWN/ANY</initializingScoreTrend>
    </scoreDirectorFactory>



    <constructionHeuristic>
        <constructionHeuristicType>ALLOCATE_ENTITY_FROM_QUEUE</constructionHeuristicType>
        <entitySorterManner>DECREASING_DIFFICULTY_IF_AVAILABLE</entitySorterManner>
        <valueSorterManner>DECREASING_STRENGTH_IF_AVAILABLE</valueSorterManner>
    </constructionHeuristic>

    <localSearch>
    <termination>
        <minutesSpentLimit>148</minutesSpentLimit>
    </termination>
    <acceptor>
        <lateAcceptanceSize>900</lateAcceptanceSize>
    </acceptor>
    <forager>
        <acceptedCountLimit>10</acceptedCountLimit>
    </forager>
    </localSearch>

    <localSearch>
        <termination>
            <minutesSpentLimit>148</minutesSpentLimit>
        </termination>
        <acceptor>
            <entityTabuSize>10</entityTabuSize>
        </acceptor>
        <forager>
            <acceptedCountLimit>1200</acceptedCountLimit>
        </forager>
    </localSearch>

</solver>

This is the application.properties related config:
timefold.solver.termination.spent-limit=305m
# To run increase CPU cores usage per solver
timefold.solver.move-thread-count=AUTO

I tried the following to override the configuration:
private final SolverManager<Timetable, String> solverManager;

solverManager.solveBuilder()
                .withProblemId(jobId)
                .withConfigOverride(new SolverConfigOverride<Timetable>().withTerminationConfig(new TerminationConfig().withMinutesSpentLimit(305L)))
                //or problem.termination instead of 305L
                .withProblemFinder(jobId_ -> jobIdToJob.get(jobId).timetable)
                .withBestSolutionConsumer(solution -> jobIdToJob.put(jobId, Job.ofTimetable(solution)))
                .withExceptionHandler((jobId_, exception) -> {
                    jobIdToJob.put(jobId, Job.ofException(exception));
                    LOGGER.error("Failed solving jobId ({}).", jobId, exception);
                })
                .run();

But I think I only override timefold.solver.termination.spent-limit.
How can I override the XML configuration so that the user can do the following configuration:

set the Construction Heuristic Phase to run for 10% (in minutes) of duration set by the user.
set each Local Search Phase to run for 45% (in minutes) of duration set by the user.

Also, what are the best practices for the XML configuration? For example, do I also have to set the spent time limit of Construction Heuristics Phase, or it is determined by the Solver? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Why did this question got downvoted? I think I wrote the question very clear and I added a snippet of my configuration.

At the moment, this is not possible. SolverConfigOverride only overrides the global termination, not individual phase terminations.
Setting terminations to construction heuristics doesn't make much sense in my opinion - CH needs to finish, and it will take as long as it needs to. A prematurely terminated CH means an uninitialized solution, and that means a useless solution.

Thank you for your answer and I will be looking forward for the improved version of the class (maybe I can help with that if you want)! I have another quick question: in my case ( the XML config from above), it would better if I set the termination on only local search phase so that CH will have plenty of time to finish and also the other local search phase will have time to do its' job?

I don't recommend setting CH phase terminations. Personally, I usually don't bother with phase terminations at all.
